# Angular 2 return data from service is not availabe after RxJs subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my map.service I have coded like this

```
loadAdminDataDiv (): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get("static/data/data.json")
                      .map(this.extractData);
  }
private extractData(res) {

      if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
      }

      //console.log(res.json());
      this.serviceData =(res.json()) ;
      return this.serviceData || { };
  }
```

Then injected inside a component as a provider and subscribed like this

```
getSubscribeData: any;
getAllvaluesFromFiles() {
    this._mapService.loadAdminDataDiv().subscribe(data => {
      this.getSubscribeData = data;

    },
      error => { console.log(error) },
      () => {
        console.log(this.getSubscribeData);  // prints the data 

      }
    );
  }

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getAllvaluesFromFiles();
    console.log(this.getSubscribeData); // prints Undefined

  }
```

Can anyone suggest me a work around with this problem ? My service is working but My subscribed data does not work outside of the subscribe method. I pointed out where I'm having problem. I need to use this `this.getSubscribeData` throughout my component as a global variable. I dont want to use shared service, Is that possible without using another service. A working code will be helpful :)

And I have to load at least 7 more variable like this. Actually I need to use these variables to pass  to d3 objects and into leaflet map and it has to be after some required interactions. Lets say, I have to load leafletmap with this `this.getSubscribeData` so I will initiate the leaflet map inside the subscribe. but if I want to use this leaflet instance outside of the method what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```ts
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getAllvaluesFromFiles();
    console.log(this.getSubscribeData); // prints Undefined
  }
```

`console.log(this.getSubscribeData)` is actually **before** `subscribe`

`subscribe()` schedules an async call for `Http` to make when the current sync thread of execution is completed.
Then your `console.log(...)` is executed.
When then *eventually* the response from the server arrives, the callback you passed to `subscribe(...)` is executed.

To be able to execute some code when the response arrived you can use for example

```ts
  getAllvaluesFromFiles() {
    return this._mapService.loadAdminDataDiv()
    .do(data => {
      this.getSubscribeData = data;
    })
    .do(() => {
        console.log(this.getSubscribeData);  // prints the data 
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
  }
```

This way an `Observable` is returned

```ts
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getAllvaluesFromFiles()
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(this.getSubscribeData); 
    })
  }
```

This way the calls are properly chained so that `console.log(...)` is executed after the data is available.

Comment: I know that but the fact is how I am going to solve it :( . I even tried in other Component's Lifecycle hooks(i.e. ngOnInit , ngAfterViewInit)

Comment: You can't solve that with lifecycle hooks. You can only solve that by properly chain calls that use `Observable` or `Promise`. For `Promise` it's `.then()` instead of `subscribe()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there any typo here in your code `return this._mapService.loadAdminDataDiv()
    do.subscribe(data => {
      this.getSubscribeData = data;
    })` It is not working for me

Comment: Yup, sorry. There is a `.` missing - fixed.

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'DoSignature<any>' , when I typed correctly :)

Comment: Sorry, there was more than a missing `.`. I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: So whenever I need to use this `this.getSubscribeData`  I have to subscribe ?

Comment: Yes. Without `subscribe()` the call won't be made. If you do the `subscribe()` inside `getAllvaluesFromFiles()` you don't get a way to chain additional code you want to execute when the response arrives.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I am still puzzled . Can You please check last para of my updated question :)

Comment: Prose is quite abstract. It's hard for me what the exact problem is that you are struggling with. I understand that you are not yet familiar with async programming. Async is quite common in the browser (because there are no threads). Maybe http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html provides some helpful insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got another way... I used static keyword for solving this problem...

```
getSubscribeData: any;
getAllvaluesFromFiles() {
this._mapService.loadAdminDataDiv().subscribe(data => {
      this.getSubscribeData = data;
      YOUR_CLASSNAME.setSubscribeData(data);
    },
    error => { console.log(error) },
    () => {
        console.log(this.getSubscribeData);  // prints the data 
      }
    );
}
ngAfterContentInit() {
this.getAllvaluesFromFiles();
 console.log(this.getSubscribeData); // prints Undefined
 console.log(YOUR_CLASSNAME.subscribeData); // prints
}

static subscribeData:any;
static setSubscribeData(data){
   YOUR_CLASSNAME.subscribeData=data;
}
```

try to use this ... hope this will help you