# Observable Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to extract the values from an observable, my subscription (component) code is as followed:

```
this.checkoutService.getDisabledDate().subscribe
(dates=>{this.formattedDate=dates}, 
(error:any)=>{console.log(error)});
```

In the 'dates' callback a console.log of this.formattedDate prints the correct values. However trying to access this.formattedDate outside of the subscription is undefined.

the service code:

```
getDisabledDate():Observable<any>{
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
    let userRequest={action_id:0};
    let disabledDate={};

    return this.http
        .post(this.deliveryUrl,userRequest,options)
        .map((r:Response)=>r.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I've performed the same action passing data over a queryParam using short form (), and it made no difference in this case. I seem to be overlooking what is necessary to pull out the information with this one.

I've looked at both: 
[Angular2 HTTP using observables subscribe showing data undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761439/angular2-http-using-observables-subscribe-showing-data-undefined)
and
[Angular 2 return data from service is not availabe after RxJs subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853620/angular-2-return-data-from-service-is-not-availabe-after-rxjs-subscribe).

Which I'm passed where their questions were answered. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you trying to access this data? In your view? Did you use *ngIf like suggested in one answer, if that is the case?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to access the data before it's available. It's only available AFTER the observable returns a value for it. Are you sure the observable is returning, i.e. `{this.formattedDate=dates` is being called before you try to access it? That's my best guess at your issue.

Comment: This is technically a dupe of how to return a value from an asynchronous function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Unfortunately Jared, the answer turned out to be much too simple even to be considered a duplicate of that thread. I was simply being impatient with my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your question where "outside" is, but if it's after the call where you get the `Observable` then this is expected behavior

```
someMethod() {
  this.checkoutService.getDisabledDate()
  .subscribe(
    // anything here is executed sometimes later when the response from the server arrives
    dates=>{ 
      this.formattedDate=dates;
      // code that depends on the result goes here
    }, 
    (error:any)=>{console.log(error)}
  );
  // this is executed first
}
```

You can't get the value outside of `subscribe`. You can use `map` and return the result for the caller to subscribe, like done in `getDisabledDate` or you move the code to one of the callbacks.

Comment: I understood that the asynchronous nature would mean code executed in the same method would finish before the observable. I had thought moving the subscribe to the constructor would leave time for the formattedDate to receive the values from the observable in ngOnInit. Turns out I was wrong. I moved a console.log(this.formattedDate) to a button, and behold it printed the values.

Comment: @Chris: You want to see Angular 2 Route resolves to pre-load data you need in your controller. Resolves guarantee that it's ready for you when a controller loads. See here: http://www.callibrity.com/blog/angular-2-route-resolves or here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html The first article is easier to read. The second is by architect-tier developers (more depth, harder to follow).

Comment: To clarify what I mean about 'outside': accessing the values of 'this.formattedDate' outside of the .subscribe(); ie. the values aren't only locally accessible to the observable, but to the scope of the receiving variable.

Comment: The question is more "when" are they available instead of "where". The part `// this is executed first` is *before* the `dates` value is available. Only `// code that depends on the result goes here` is *after* the `dates` is available.