# Angular can't read value of 'undefined' - unable to read value of 'casestudy' in the setTitle() method?

Tags: angular6

This is my component:

```
export class CaseStudyDetailComponent implements OnInit {

casestudy: CaseStudy;

constructor ( private caseStudyService: CaseStudyService, private route: ActivatedRoute, public titleService: Title ) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: { Handle: string }) => {
        this.caseStudyService.getCaseStudy(params.Handle).subscribe(casestudy => this.casestudy = casestudy);
    });

    this.titleService.setTitle(this.casestudy.Handle);

}
}
```

This is the service it is calling:

```
    getCaseStudy(Handle: string): Observable<CaseStudy> {
    return this.http.get<CaseStudy>(`${environment.apiPath}/project/handle/${Handle}`);
}
```

I want to be able to access the value of 'casestudy' in the 'setTitle()' method. I might potentially just be misunderstanding expected behaviour or have my syntax wrong.

Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: What does your `CaseStudyService` look like? Can you add more detail to your question? Please read [How To Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on the correct way to ask a question.

Comment: I've edited my original question, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945817/observable-undefined)

Comment: Have you logged out the value of `casestudy` returned from your service, to make sure it's actually got a value?

Comment: `this.caseStudyService.getCaseStudy(params.Handle).subscribe((casestudy: any) => { console.log('Returned, casestudy); this.casestudy = casestudy); });`

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting back a value from my service, that's not the issue, but thanks for the suggestion, I just double checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your console.log gets excecuted before your subscribe can set the response in the caseStudy.

To fix this put the console.log method in the subscribe

```
this.caseStudyService.getCaseStudy().subscribe(caseStudy => {
  ... code
  console.log(caseStudy);
});
```

Comment: Once you've assigned `casestudy` to `this.casestudy`, you can access it from another method. The reason your `console.log` is empty, is because it's executed before the call is complete. See my comment on your question to check if you're actually getting a value returned from your service.