# How to create array of objects from http.get

Tags: arrays, angular, http, object

I have http.get and it's impossible for me to create array of objects. Can you help me ? I need to create loop on array of returned objects and i can't do this.

```
export class Link {
  idStat: String;
  idAccount: String;
}

links: Link [];

router.get('/linkGetAll', function(req, res, next) {
  Link.find(function (err, products) {
  if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});

getAllLinks(){
  return this.http.get('/main/linkGetAll');
}

 this.api.getAllLinks().subscribe((data) => {
  this.links = data;
})

for(let item in this.links)
{
  DOESN'T WORK
}
```

Comment: What do you receive in "data" exactly? Also this.links will be filled once subscribe returns data from "getAllLinks" call. Try to put your for loop inside .subscribe((data) => { block

Comment: mongodb table data

Comment: Observables are *asynchronous*, that's the whole point. If you want to access the data, do it in the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 return data from service is not availabe after RxJs subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853620/angular-2-return-data-from-service-is-not-availabe-after-rxjs-subscribe)

Answer (score 0):

```
getAllLinks(){
  return this.http.get('/main/linkGetAll')
    .pipe(map(res => {

       // do something here
       // res.forEach() or res.map()
       return 'it';
     })
   );
}
```

Before going to

`for(let item in this.links)
{
  DOESN'T WORK
}`

Ensure that this.links has data in it.(use async/await along with toPromise())

Comment: Async/await is for *promises*, not observables.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, when you modify a response, it certainly not an `Observable`. so you can use `toPromise()` on it then use async/await..

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this section](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient) about HTTP of the Angular tutorial and the [Angular API](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get).

The get method accepts a type:

```
get<T>(...): Observable<T>
```

so you could modify your implementation of getAllLinks:

```
getAllLinks(): Observable<Link[] {
    return this.http.get<Link[]>('/main/linkGetAll');
}
```

Now you should should be able to iterate the response:

```
getAllLinks().subscribe(links => {
    links.forEach(link => // do what you need);
}
```